# Use GraphQL with in existing spring boot rest api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql

We have few existing rest apis written in spring boot to fetch different data in our project? Now we are exploring options to use GraphQL. But we don't want rest endpoints & response to change since it is being consumed by many UI/backend applications. Can anyone suggest proper way to use GraphQL within existing API without changing rest endpoints and Response type?